# whats the default padding for a jquery button?

Tags: jquery-ui-button

whats the default padding for a jquery button? tried to download and search the dev pack... :( did not fint it :(

Comment: I would open the jquery ui button demo page and use FireBug to check the padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stylesheet:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
  padding: .4em 1em;
}
```

As one of the commenters mentioned, it's very easy to find this out by using the firefox plugin [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or by using the [web inspector](http://mactips.info/2010/07/use-safari-5s-web-inspector) in Safari/Chrome